# Executing PHP with CronJobs in CentOS 6.4 not working?

Tags: centos, cron, php

So I've spent around 2-3 hours now and some times researching, I found several of the same responses online but none seem to work!

I'm trying to execute a PHP script every minute (as a test), but it doesn't work.

[image: This is crontab in /etc/crontab]
I honestly don't see what's wrong with that script. So I've went to check the logs and I get this;

> May  1 19:59:01 *namehere* crond[1112]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
>   May  1 19:59:01 *namehere* crond[1112]: (CRON) bad username (/etc/crontab)

I am quite confused, any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have LAMP installed and php-cli if that matters.

EDIT:

I finally made it execute! Thanks to the poster below! However, I now have another problem, I get emailed an error 
[image]
My script includes other scripts, when I was on cPanel (shared hosting), it worked perfectly, but now it doesn't, what could be the problem?

Comment: This is another programming/PHP related problem that you have updated, I strongly suggest posting is as a separate question on stackoverflow.com as it will also require more details on how your program is structured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have some version of cron which expects a `user-name` parameter before the command. It is even in the header, just a bit *concealed*:

```
*  *  *  *  * <user-name> <command to be executed>
```

Try this (replace root with whatever user php/apache runs at):

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php
```

Also, note that some distributions have separate `php.ini` configurations depending if it is used via command line (cli) or as apache module etc. So if you run into more problems, make sure your `php.ini` files match (check `/etc/php`).

**Update**

For absolute paths to work, have your includes like this:

```
include __FILE__ . '../inc/databases.php';
```

Note the added `__FILE__` which returns absolue path to current running script. You will have to update all `include` and `require`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @edvinas.me - You've got it to work, great! but now I have another problem: [link](http://i.imgur.com/hXOlS9F.png) The script also includes files from another script, when i was on cPanel (shared hosting) it worked perfectly, but now it doesn't? Do you think you know what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The relative paths do not work, you have to use absolute paths or something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844641/how-to-change-the-path-to-php-ini-in-php-cli-version Feel free to post another question on StackExchange. Also don't forget to accept answers that helped you!

Comment: actually I think there is an easier way I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I'll have a test shortly. But I'm sure there is a way where I won't need to provide an absolute path, seeing if cPanel and zPanel could successfully do it right? @edvinas.me